Logging values whenever a test suite fails in Karate UI, executed through the command line
I'm trying to find a way to log the trace-id of a browsing session when a Feature fails, so I'm able to locate its logs easily on our monitoring solution. This property is generated client side, so it's not immediately available in the headers when initially loading the application.
I should be able to set the value in a hidden input, which then could be retrieved by Karate, but I don't know if there's a hook or something, that is able to read the DOM and log this value whenever a test fails.
Also, I'm using the command line to execute tests in a non-java project, so I understand it limits my options.

My suggestion is make a separate API call using Karate's core HTTP client capability similar to the guidance for file-download. Making a GET to a UI page should be good enough if you only care about headers. There are ways to re-use the cookies from a UI driver if needed, just copy them over to the API call using the cookie keyword.
Then you should be able to inspect headers and get the value into a variable.
* def traceId = karate.response.header('trace-id')

Or maybe writing a JS utility function for grabbing it out of the DOM is worth it. Your idea of having it within a hidden-field should work, or you could have it set as a cookie, or an HTML data attribute on the <body>, there are many options.
EDIT: since question is mostly about reporting on error, see if the afterScenario hook helps, there is some work on improving it here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2634

The issue isn't really about retrieving the traceId, but mostly about if there's a way to make whatever logic used to retrieve it, log its value on each test suite failure.

@JuanDelaCruz made an edit, hope it helps - or do consider contributing code
